# Call viewcontroller webview method from appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I've got a webview in my viewcontroller.

I've integrated facebook connect that throws userLoggedIn + userLoggedOut functions from the AppDelegate.m file.

I need to run javascript into the webview from these logged in/out functions, like so:
[ _crawlWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"alert('hey ho')" ];

The above line works perfectly from the viewcontroller that holds the webview, but not from appDelegate. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward the request from the `AppDelegate` to the `ViewController` that owns the WebView.

If that line of code works inside the ViewController

```
[ _crawlWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"alert('hey ho')" ];
```

First make sure your `AppDelegate` has a pointer to your `ViewController`, and second, make sure that the webView is available through a property.

Then from your AppDelegate you use both the pointer and the property to end up with something like this:

```
[myViewController.crawlWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"alert('hey ho')" ];
```